# JpaRepository caches newly created object. How to refresh it?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JpaRepository persisting newly created entity in Spring MVC app. This entity looks like this (very simplified):

```
@Entity
public class Translation {

    .....

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Version version;

    ....

}
```

and Version entity:

```
@Entity
public class Version {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "version_code")
    private long code;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "version", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Translation> translations;

}
```

I create a translation object like this

```
            TranslationDTO t = new TranslationDTO();
            t.setText(translationText);
            ClientVersionDTO version = new ClientVersionDTO();
            version.setId(11);
            t.setVersion(version);
```

where 11 is a version that exists in the database already from the very beginning. Please notice that I do not set values for `name` and `code` of ClientVersionDTO.

Then I have a service that persists new object (I use `dozer` library to convert DTO to entities)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TranslationsServiceImpl implements TranslationsService {
    @Override
    public Long create(TranslationDTO translationDTO) {
        Translation translation = translationsConverter.unconvert(translationDTO);
        Translation t = translationRepository.saveAndFlush(translation);

        Translation t2 = translationRepository.findOne(t.getId());

        // !!!! t2.getVersion() returns version where no values are set to 'code' and 'name'

        return t2.getId();
    }
}
```

Please notice my comment "t2.getVersion() returns version where no values are set to 'code' and 'name'" - I was expecting so that when I fetch the data from the database, I would get a `Version` object right from the database with `code` and `name` values set. However they are not set. So basically what I get as a `t2.getVersion()` object is the same object as in input argument `translationDTO.getVersion()`.  How can they I re-invalidate the `Version` object?

*UPDATE* tried moving @Transactional to JpaRepository, but still the same result.

Comment: Do you probably mean "Spring MVC"? It is because you've written "Sprint MVC"

Comment: Yes, thanks. Amended typos.

Comment: Try to move your @Transactional to your repository for a test

Comment: benjamin.d, just tried with no luck.

Comment: found a better solution? I've a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491551/refresh-and-fetch-an-entity-after-save-jpa-spring-data-hibernate

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate, this is the expected result.  When you call `translationRepository.saveAndFlush(translation)` and `translationRepository.findOne(t.getId())` one after the other, they hit the same Hibernate session which maintains a cache of all objects that it has worked on.  Therefore, the second call simply returns the object passed to the first.  There is nothing in those two lines that would have forced Hibernate to fire a `SELECT` query on the database for the `Version` entity.

Now, the JPA spec does have a `refresh` method on the `EntityManager` interface.  Unfortunately, Spring Data JPA does not expose this method using its `JpaRepository` interface.  If this method was available, you could have done `t = translationRepository.saveAndFlush(translation)` and then `versionRepository.refresh(t.getVersion())` to force the JPA provider to synchronize the version entity with the database.

Implementing this method is not difficult.  Just extend `SimpleJpaRepository` class from Spring Data JPA and implement the method yourself.  For details see [adding custom behaviour to all Spring Data JPA repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

An alternate would be to load the version entity as `versionRepository.findOne(version.getId())` before setting it on the translation.  Since you can hard-code version id in your code, your versions seem to be static.  You can therefore mark your `Version` entity as `@Immutable` and `@Cacheable` (the former is a Hibernate-specific annotation).  That way, `versionRepository.findOne(version.getId())` should not hit the database every time it is called.

Comment: thanks, indeed I also came into conclusion and used the second approach. Btw, version is not harcoded, it's here just for simplicity.