# Refresh and fetch an entity after save (JPA/Spring Data/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I've these two simple entities `Something` and `Property`.
The `Something` entity has a many-to-one relationship to `Property`, so when I create a new `Something` row, I assign an existing `Property`.

**Something:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "something")
public class Something implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String owner;

    @ManyToOne
    private Property property;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Something{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", owner='" + getOwner() + "'" +
            ", property=" + getProperty() +
            "}";
    }
```

**Property:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "property")
public class Property implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "shape")
    private String shape;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "dimension")
    private Integer dimension;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Property{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", shape='" + getShape() + "'" +
            ", color='" + getColor() + "'" +
            ", dimension='" + getDimension() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

This is the `SomethingRepository` (Spring):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface SomethingRepository extends JpaRepository<Something,Long> {
    
}
```

Through a REST controller and a JSON, I want to create a new `Something`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SomethingResource {

    private final SomethingRepository somethingRepository;

    public SomethingResource(SomethingRepository somethingRepository) {
        this.somethingRepository = somethingRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/somethings")
    public Something createSomething(@RequestBody Something something) throws URISyntaxException {
        Something result = somethingRepository.save(something);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON in input (the `property` `id` 1 is an existing row in the database):

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "owner": "MySelf",
  "property": {
    "id": 1
  }
```

}

The problem is: after the method `.save(something)`, the variable `result` contains the persisted entity, but without the fields of field `property`, validated (they are `null`):

Output JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "MyName",
  "owner": "MySelf",
  "property": {
    "id": 1,
    "shape": null,
    "color": null,
    "dimension": null
  }
}
```

I expect that they are validated/returned after the save operation.

To workaround this, I have to inject/declare the `EntityManager` in the REST controller, and call the method `EntityManager.refresh(something)` (or I have to call a `.findOne(something.getId())` method to have the complete persisted entity):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Transactional
public class SomethingResource {

    private final SomethingRepository somethingRepository;
    
    private final EntityManager em;

    public SomethingResource(SomethingRepository somethingRepository, EntityManager em) {
        this.somethingRepository = somethingRepository;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @PostMapping("/somethings")
    public Something createSomething(@RequestBody Something something) throws URISyntaxException {
        Something result = somethingRepository.save(something);
        em.refresh(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

With this workaround, I've the expected saved entith (with a correct JSON):

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "MyName",
  "owner": "MySelf",
  "property": {
    "id": 1,
    "shape": "Rectangle",
    "color": "Red",
    "dimension": 50
  }
}
```

Is there an automatic method/annotation, with JPA or Spring or Hibernate, in order to have the "complete" persisted entity?

I would like to avoid to declare the `EntityManager` in every REST or Service class, or I want avoid to call the `.findOne(Long)` method everytime I want the new refreshed persisted entity.

Comment: IMHO you are expecting to much from a "dump" repository here. If you need the full Property, load it first (findById) and use this as a reference.

Answer (score 89):

Instead of defining `EntityManager` in each of your **resource**, you can define it once by creating a **Custom** JpaRepository. [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html)

Then use the `refresh` of your `EntityManager` in each of your repository directly.

Refer the below example:

**CustomRepository Interface**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import java.io.Serializable;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  void refresh(T t);
}
```

**CustomRepository Implementation**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
    implements CustomRepository<T, ID> {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public CustomRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void refresh(T t) {
    entityManager.refresh(t);
  }
}
```

**Enable Custom JPARepository in Spring Boot Application Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories (repositoryBaseClass = CustomRepositoryImpl.class)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Your Something Repository**

```
public interface SomethingRepository extends CustomRepository<Something, Long> {

}
```

**Use Refresh directly in SomethingResource** (Assuming Something is an Entity)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Transactional
public class SomethingResource {

    private final SomethingRepository somethingRepository;

    public SomethingResource(SomethingRepository somethingRepository) {
        this.somethingRepository = somethingRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/somethings")
    public Something createSomething(@RequestBody Something something) throws URISyntaxException {
        Something result = somethingRepository.save(something);
        somethingRepository.refresh(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean, clear, reusable. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I am getting error "interface required" for repository "public interface SomethingRepository extends CustomRepository<Something, Long>{}"

Comment: @Shailesh its hard to tell what is wrong without seeing your code. Can you please share your code? What I can say without seeing the code is to validate that `CustomRepository` is an interface not a class in your code.

Comment: for me, it throws exception: No property refresh found for type `Something`, can you explain me why

Comment: @Khuynh Thành Chi Luyến , you  missed repositoryBaseClass = CustomRepositoryImpl.class line. It solves your problem

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Getting following error `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'refresh' found for type 'User'!`

Answer (score 17):

This is not a problem with Spring Data / JPA, but multiple suboptimal decisions you made in your code. Thus, the problem cannot be solved by tweaking some JPA mappings or tweaking your repository interface. At least not without creating additional negative side-effects that effectively worsen the situation. Let me try to go through the issues one by one:

### 1. You're not modelling aggregates

An entity managed by a Spring Data repository needs to follow aggregate semantics to work properly, which means that, in the case of JPA, `@ManyToOne` relationships do not have a place in such a model. As you didn't go into whether a repository for `Property` exists, there are two options:

#### a) No `PropertyRepository` exists

A `@ManyToOne` relationship is invalid, as aggregates (your `Something`) need to govern the consistency of the entities they contain. A many-to-one relationship allows two `Something`s to exist, which subverts that requirement. A change to one of them could render the constraints in the other invalid.

#### b) A `PropertyRepository` exists (i.e. `Property` is an aggregate itself)

The relationship must not be modeled as a full object reference but as a by-id reference. If that's the case, the entire question disappears, as you'd just bind the identifier from the request anyway, resolve it for presentation purposes and create a JSON response through some DTO.

### 2. You're (ab)using your domain entity to bind partial request data

You've designed a `Something` to capture the state related to the `Property` instances, and now magically expect a persistence mechanism to detect, whether the fields of `Property` that are `null` are intentionally `null` (i.e. are supposed to be set to null). Or whether they're supposed to be filled up with the actual values available in the current state of the instance that you only provided the identifier for. That's impossible. The persistence mechanism cannot know that.

You have overloaded the aggregate type with two concerns. Maintaining aggregate state and acting as capture mechanism for incomplete data. The solution is to rather use a dedicated type to achieve the latter and introduce a dedicated mapping step from the bound request body to the entity model. That may include a resolution of the `Property` identifier (in case of 1b applying) or not (for 1a).

### Summary

There's no need for a custom repository extension that basically leaks implicit JPA concepts into calling code, any kind of JPA `EntityManager.merge(…)`/`(….refresh(…))` Kung-Fu or even interacting with the abstraction (`Session`) behind the abstraction (JPA) behind the abstraction (Spring Data). All you need is proper modelling and separation of the concerns “managing aggregate state” and “binding request data to an object”.

Answer (score 11):

That's not enough:

```
Something result = somethingRepository.save(something);
```

You need to manually merge the incoming entity:

```
Something dbSomething = somethingRepository.findOne(
    Something.class, something.getId()
);
dbSomething.setName(something.getName());
dbSomething.setOwner(something.getOwner());

somethingRepository.save(dbSomething);
```

Since the `property` attribute is using the default [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/), the entity should have the `property` attribute initialized.

But, that's strange to call the Repository twice from the REST controller. You should have a Service layer that does all that in a `@Transactional` service method. That way, you don't need to resave the entity since it's already managed.

```
@Transactional
public Something mergeSomething(Something something) {
    Something dbSomething = somethingRepository.findOne(
        Something.class, something.getId()
    );
    dbSomething.setName(something.getName());
    dbSomething.setOwner(something.getOwner());

    return dbSomething;
}
```

Now, you need to carefully merge every property you sent. In your case, if you send `null` for `property` you should decide whether you should nullify the `@ManyToOne` reference or not. So, it depends on your current application business logic requirements.

### Update

If you make sure you always send back the same entity you previously fetched, you could just use `merge`.

```
em.merge(result);
```

But your `property` attribute is just an id, and not an actual child entity, so you have to resolve that yourself in the Service layer.

Comment: I used the repository in the REST only for simplicity and shortness. I don't understand why you manually merge the incoming entity, I don't have problems about merging between the in and out entity. I've problems only with the `property` field (and its fields). I tried to move the save operation in a `@Service` class and in a method marked as `@Transactional`, but nothing change. I don't understand why Spring and Hibernate don't retrieve and don't attach the fields to `property` field. Only the `id`. In the input JSON I don't need and don't want to specify their value. I want a reload from DB.

Comment: javax.transaction or springframework.transaction for the import?

Answer (score 7):

In Spring Boot JpaRepository:

If our modifying query changes entities contained in the persistence context, then this context becomes outdated.

In order to fetch the entities from the database with latest record.

Use @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)

@Modifying annotation has clearAutomatically attribute which defines whether it should clear the underlying persistence context after executing the modifying query.

Example:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE NetworkEntity n SET n.network_status = :network_status WHERE n.network_id = :network_id")
        int expireNetwork(@Param("network_id") Integer network_id,  @Param("network_status") String network_status);
```

Comment: That did not work. I have a case that some columns modified after an insert by a database trigger. Yet those columns appear to be null in my entity after a save. I guess extending EntityManager and calling refresh method is the only solution for this problem.

Comment: This works, but you'll likely also want to use it with `flushAutomatically = true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062549/71066 for more info.

Comment: `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)` also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the property with a proxy generated using `session.load`

```
        something.setProperty(session.load(Property.class, something.getProperty().getId()))
        Something result = somethingRepository.save(something);
        return result;
```

Now the result will have the entire property object loaded from the db

Answer (score -1):

By the time you persist the entity it will be in managed state so if you just call `something.getProperty();` it loads from the database and fills the `property` value of the `something` entity

```
public Something save(Something something) {
    em.persist(something);
    something.getProperty();
    return something;
}
```

so normally when you have many-to-one relationship that should be fetched automatically. If not calling the getters of the objects in entity will fill them too by firing a new DB Find request.

Comment: Tried to call the .getProperty() method in various point of the code; I've also seen this on some tutorials, but in my case nothing happen, it does not work. Very strange. I'm trying to find some solutions with .getProperty() (also using some annotations like PostLoad, PostPersist, JsonGetter and LAZY/EAGER fetch).

Comment: did you do that in the same method of  persist

Comment: No. I did that in the REST controller after the method .save. I can't access to .save method because it is a Spring method, present in the repository interface (it extends JpaRepository)

Comment: can't help. At least in JPA it works because you write your em.persist() method in JPA