# Insert trigger updates the record, get the updated value in jpa

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, triggers

I have an insert query performed by spring boot jpa. The insert query triggers a DB trigger, which updates a column, `slug`. Is there a way to get the updated value as part of the same jpa transaction (instead of reading the record again from the DB or using a Stored procedure)?

Following code simplified for question sake.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "user")
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping
    public Invite saveUser(@Validated @RequestBody User user) {
        // user.slug is null
        User newUser = userRepo.save(user);
        // DB insert
        // DB trigger has logic to update user.slug column in DB 
        // newUser.slug is null; in spite of DB having a value for the slug column
    }
}
```

Note: I tried what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48878923/234110) and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling `entityManager.refresh()` explicitly.

Comment: what a terrible answer, wth is entityManager.refresh()?