# How do you get changes made by a database trigger back to the entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, triggers, transactions, spring-3

How can I refresh the entity inside a transactional method so that the properties changed by a trigger become visible?

I have a trigger that sets/updates certain columns before an insert/update. Postgres example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER customer_befins
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_update_managementfields();
```

On the backend side I have a transactional method that creates and returns the entity:

**UPDATE:** Added entity mapping.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "IdGenerator", strategy = "demo.IdGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "IdGenerator")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "bpchar", updatable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "somedate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
  private LocalDateTime someDate;

  public BaseEntity() {
  }

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public LocalDateTime getSomeDate() {
    return this.someDate;
  }

  public void setSomeDate(LocalDateTime someDate) {
    this.someDate = someDate;
  }
}

@Entity
public class CustomerEntity extends BaseEntity {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CustomerEntity> {

}

@Service
public class CustomerService {
  private final EntityManager entityManager; 
  private final ICustomerRepository repository;

  public CustomerService(EntityManager entityManager, ICustomerRepository repository) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Transactional
  public CustomerEntity createEntity(...) {
    CustomerEntity entity = new CustomerEntity();
    // ...
    entity = repository.save(entity);
    // I need the values changed by the trigger here
    return entity;
  }
```

After the save, the properties changed by the trigger are not visible in the entity. In this example the column of the property "someDate" is changed by the trigger.
First, I tried to refresh the entity via "entityManager.refresh(entity);" directly after calling "repository.save()".
However, this leads to:

```
jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database
```

I already checked the following questions, but I did not found a working solution:

- [Refresh and fetch an entity after save (JPA/Spring Data/Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491551/refresh-and-fetch-an-entity-after-save-jpa-spring-data-hibernate)
- [A field value returned by a trigger after insert is not synchronized in JPA with a method annotated with @Transactional and saveAndFlush() invocation [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541734/a-field-value-returned-by-a-trigger-after-insert-is-not-synchronized-in-jpa-with)

Comment: Could you share your entity mapping please ?

Comment: @AmineABBAOUI I just added the mapping.