# Changes not reflected after "refreshing" entity with Spring JPA

Tags: java, orm, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I'm strugglingtrying to "refresh" an entity (Foo) that look like this:

```
public class Foo {

    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooRef", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bar> bars;
}


public class Bar {

    //...
    @Column(name = "FOO_ID")
    private Long fooRef;
    @Column(name = "STATE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private State state;
}
```

As [Spring JPA doesn't implement the refresh method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146783/jparepository-caches-newly-created-object-how-to-refresh-it#28300145), I just query the entity again. This is the code that it doesn't work and I dont know why:

```
for(int i=0; i<MAX_RETRIES; i++) {

    List<Bar> bars = foo.getBars();

    // check bars state

    if(someBarIsBad) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

        }
    } else {
        break;
    }

    foo = fooRepo.findById(fooId);  // "refresh"
}
```

The goal is to continue retry until all bars have the desired state.
The test I'm doing is placing a breakpoint at the last instruction of the loop, so when it break, I go the the table and change the state of all of the bars to the desired one to then exit the loop. The thing is that the new returned `foo`, the `bars` doesn't reflect the change I made.

I tried to remove the sleep, but that is not the problem. I think it must be something with the mapping.

Comment: I suggest that the problem is in `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. The `bars` will be updated, when you tried to use them. Try to do something like this after refresh `for (Bar bar : foo.getBars()) { sout(bar);} `. I hope this will trigger lazy initialization.

Comment: I tested removing the LAZY fetching, but it is the same result. Anyway, that should not be problem as I'm retriving the `bars` on the same scope I retrieve `foo`. What do you mean with `sout`  ? Is a jpa method?

Comment: nonono, `sout` is shortcut for `System.out.println()`. Removing fetch is incorrect, cause for `OneToMany` relation - default fetch type is LAZY. So this removing changes nothing. Try to change fetch from LAZY to EAGER. And yes, you are right - the scope the same, but difference is in direct and undirect using Bar entity table.

Comment: This is really strange. I tried with eagger fetch, nothing. I tried retriving directly `barRepo.findByFooRef` and neither. And I already assure I make the change correctly with commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because everything is running in a single transaction. This causes JPA to not reload the entity from the database, but to return the one it already has in the session.

Either make sure you are in a new transaction on every "refresh" or evict the entity from the session, so it has to get reloaded again.

Comment: Make sense. But I'm not sure how I should isolate the transaction. I taked `fooRepo.findById(fooId)` and wrapped it on a method annotated with `@Transactional`. Still doesn't return me an updated version.

Comment: The important part is that the code you showed in your question ISN'T wrapped in a method annotated with `@Transactional`

Comment: I did, both, the code above and `getFoo(ID)` are transactional. Still the same :(

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was not aware of Isolation levels. I anotated getFoo(ID) with `@Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`